# Rails: link_to does not generate 2 content_tag within

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want generate this in view

```
    <li>
      <%= link_to pop_path do  %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span>
        Trending
      <% end %>
    </li>
```

So I made a helper

```
def nav_link2(link_text, link_path)
  content_tag(:li, class: 'active') do
    link_to link_path do
      content_tag(:span, nil, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-star")
      content_tag(:span, link_text)
    end
  end
end
```

However, it can only generate 1 `span` within, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate the two `content_tags` in the `link_to` block, since only the last line from a block is returned and thus printed.

Join the two strings generated by `content_tag` and use `html_safe` so it gets rendered properly:

```
link_to link_path do
  content_tag(:span, nil, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-star") +
    content_tag(:span, link_text)
end.html_safe
```